# Django - where can I find the output of print() statements in production?

Tags: django, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean

Django - where can I find the output of `print()` statements in production? I'm using a Digital Ocean droplet, Ubuntu 16.04.

I don't see `print()` output in access.log or error.log files. Is this something I need to set up manually?

Comment: What are you using to run the Django project? Apache with mod_cgi?

Comment: Hi @Ezphares I'm using Nginx.

Comment: you can find it in the `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: @NalinDobhal, thanks but when I check that I don't see the output of any of my `print()` statements. I see a lot of lines that all include `[UFW BLOCK]`

Comment: @Jake1986 may be you dont have any new logs, try to look into syslog.1. are you using gunicorn?

Comment: @NalinDobhal thanks I checked syslog.1 and I do see my `print()` outputs in there, although they are buried among kernel messages. And yes, I am using gunicorn.

Comment: @Jake1986 i guess in your gunicorn.service, you are using `--access-logfile -`, `-` means print data to stdout. refer to [docs](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#logging) to configure your logging.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it using a Django funcionality called Logging.

You can look at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/

To setup:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

To print:

```
log.debug('Message that you want')
```

The log will go where your django logs are pointed.